# How to compile and execute 32bit C program on 64bit Windows

Tags: gcc, 32bit-64bit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a 64bit Intel based machine and want to compile and run 32bit C code in my command prompt. I have bash installed via (Windows Subsystems for Linux) and am using gcc and have the gcc-multilib installed so I can compile using the -m32 tag. The program compiles fine but comes up with this error when I try to run:

```
bash: ./32test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL only supports 64-bit ELF binaries.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/390

You can try to build with a native Windows compiler or in Cygwin instead.